Best way to create a Bot User with Read-only access to all objects (existing and future) and records
We need a bot User to pull data from Salesforce to external systems. It should have Read-only access to all data in Salesforce.
I'm thinking to clone Sys Admin, and remove "Edit Access" from all Objects...
However, with end-of-life of Permissions on Profiles coming, is this best practices?
If I were to use Perm Set, that would be a lot of time clicking to give back "Read Access". Or is there a really fast way to do this with workbench or Dev Console?
I also have the requirement that when a new Object is added to the Org (including from a Managed Package), it should automatically be added to this User (via PermSet or Profile). I can't guarantee the developer adding the object will check the box for Sys Admin Read-only profile or add the Perm Set. Is Flow my best option here?
